# How can I use a function from another file in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to create a file (function.js) for a function that does this:

```
let i = 0;
    if (this === that) {
        i = 0;
    } else {
       i = 1;
    }
```

I would then like to add it to (this.js)

```
import function from "./function";
class Example extends Component {
    state = {
        test
    };
    render() {
        function()
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{this.state.test.sample[i].name}</h1>
        </div>
```

Comment: export the function.js first. then you can import it.

Comment: Hi, try exporting function in functions file, and import it in your other file. so the exporting statement would be like export default functionName;

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do something like:

function.js

```
const doSomething = function() {
let i = 0;
    if (this === that) {
        i = 0;
    } else {
       i = 1;
    }

}

export default doSomething;
```

App.js (for example):

```
import doSomething from "./function";

class Example extends Component {
    state = {
        test
    };
    render() {
        doSomething()
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{this.state.test.sample[i].name}</h1>
        </div>
     )
```

Comment: You are not assigning value of i to anything in your main component. for example you can return i from your function, and then after importing function into your file, you can do: let result = doSomething(); then you have the value of i, to assign it to whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you so much, holy crap, that makes so much sense!

Answer (score 15):

there are multiple ways to do it.

#### 1st

If you are going to create multiple functions in that file

```
export const one = () => {
let i = 0;
    if (this === that) {
        i = 0;
    } else {
       i = 1;
    }
}

export const two = () => {
let i = 0;
    if (this === that) {
        i = 0;
    } else {
       i = 1;
    }
}
```

And then import and use it

```
import { 
one, 
two 
} from "./functions"
```

#### 2nd

You can use `export defualt`

```
export default = function() {
  let i = 0;
  if (this === that) {
    i = 0;
  } else {
    i = 1;
  }
}
```

and then simply use it by doing this

```
import function from "./function";
```

Comment: this is a good answer, shows how to export multiple functions from a single file

Comment: very useful example when tehre are more functions in external file. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`function.js` has below code

```
const funcName = function() {
  let i = 0;
  if (this === that) {
    i = 0;
  } else {
    i = 1;
  }
}

export default funcName;
```

And you can use it in `this.js` as below -

```
import funcName from "./function"; // or wherever the file is saved

class Example extends Component {
    state = {
        test
    };
    render() {
        funcName();
      return (
        <div>
            <h1>{this.state.test.sample[i].name}</h1>
        </div>
       );
     }
```

Comment: wrong error sorry, its actually showing "'i' is not defined"

Answer (score 2):

The `function` keyword is a reserved identifier.

On the browser you need some kind of bundler tool which will allow to `import` from a js module. On the server you can just `require(path/to/file)`. I suggest you look at `create-react-app` for a fully functionnal `react` setup. The basic setup contains example about the JS module system (see docs below).

In return your file needs to export the symbols you want to use.

In a directory with `a.js` and `b.js` where `b` wants to import a symbol from `a`

```
// file a.js
export function myFunction () {}


// file b.js
import { myFunction } from "./a";
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Answer (score 1):

Export your function like this in function.js

```
export function funcName() {
   //function stuff
   let i = 1;
   return i;
}
```

the import would be

```
import { funcName } from './function';

console.log(`value of i is ${funcName()}`);
```

Comment: How would you import that?

Comment: @Andy import { funcName } from 'functions.js';

Comment: You should include that in your answer because the OP is trying to import with `import fn from './fn'` and might not understand the difference.

Comment: This is not working, I keep getting i is not defined

Comment: @user10916917 try the updated code. I had no idéa you actually wanted the variable from the function.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

another-file.js

```
export function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

export function ShowText() {
  return '<h1>This is a sample Page</h1>';
}
```

App.js

```
import {sum, ShowText} from './another-file';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>5 + 5 = {sum(5, 5)}</h2>
      <hr />

      <h2>Text From another file: {ShowText()}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```