# Call function from another React file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function in a .react.js file that works fine in that file that imports as undefined in a different file.

So in in file1.react.js:

```
const functionName= function (): React.Node {
  return (
    <// insret code here>
  );
};

export default functionName;
```

and in file2.react.js:

```
import {functionName} from 'file1.react'
```

But when I try to call `{functionName()}` it says functionName isn't a function and when I do `{typeof functionName}` it says it's undefined.

FYI: I referenced question [43262599](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262599/call-js-function-from-another-file-in-react) and [54199264](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54199264/how-can-i-use-a-function-from-another-file-in-react/54199395) when trying to get this to work.

Comment: Either change your export to say `export functionName` or change the import to `import functionName from 'file1.react'`

Comment: try to look here: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/44309439/5427820](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44309439/5427820),
but you can try to export directly your function by doing that:
`export const  functionName = () => ( // your jsx );` and after that use `import {functionName} from 'file1.react'`

Comment: In addition to the named vs default export problem, if your import statement is actually ...`from 'file1.react'`, you'll need to add the relative path — imports without paths are for globals and node modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this pictures is self-explanatory and will help you to know where  you are going wrong

[image]